# Notation: What is $\delta_{mn}$?

Tags: notation

In a textbook, I found this relation for eigenvalues of total angular momentum:
$$(L^2)_{mn} = \langle l,m \rvert L^2 \lvert l,n\rangle = \hbar^2l(l+1)\delta_{mn}$$

What is the $\delta_{mn}$ refer to? The book does not explain.

[source](http://books.google.com/books?id=frvBRTnWpEIC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=angular%20momentum%20matrix%20of%20l%2b,%20l-,%20l2&source=bl&ots=VHe37ROpl9&sig=2hdP3dqRzpAFaCeEDhebjJgf218&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-QdcUuD2OMad2QXDuoGQDA&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=angular%20momentum%20matrix%20of%20l%2b,%20l-,%20l2&f=false)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that only when *m* and *n* are equal the value is 1, otherwise it is zero.

Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta for more information.